# Set image content from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, base64

I am making a ajax request in jquery as below. This ajax request gets images dynamically. And the image is always different image depending on the value of `num`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ABC.php?num=1",
    success: function(response) {
          if(response == 1) {
                //some code
          }
          else {
                // Here I am not able to set image content.
                $("#image").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,' + response + '");
          }
    }
});
```

Is there a way to set image content using the response of the ajax request. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some unneeded single quotes there. Use this:

```
$("#image").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + response);
```

Comment: I tried by removing the quotes and using exactly what you said. It did not worked. When I inspect the img tag it shows the response as part of `src`

Comment: Uhh yea, that's the point. What is the value of `response`? It has to be a base64 encoding of a binary that is a valid PNG-image.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#image').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + response + '" />');
```

You need to send the image back base64 encoded, look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use jquery but this worked for me: 
`$(".avatar").html('<img src="' + user.avatar_url + '" />');` 
Here i am adding an image to a class and avatar_url comes from the response from the server.